# Recover Untitled Document 1 from gedit

Tags: xubuntu, gedit

I have an unsaved document opened in gedit on Xubuntu 13.10. A bug caused gedit's main window to disappear and only the title bar is still visible, reading "Untitled Document 1".

Is there a way to recover the typed text from the running but defunct session of gedit? Are "Untitled Documents" stored somewhere temporarily?

Comment: `cat /path/"Untitled Document 1~" > ~/Desktop/file.txt`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where the file is located or if it solely exists in RAM. Is it maybe possible to issue console commands to running instances of programs?

Comment: `locate "Untitled Document 1~"`

Comment: Returns nothing. :-(

Comment: Did you actually save the document as "Untitled Document" (or was this purely in memory on an unsaved text)?

Comment: You can try `find ~ -type f -name Untitled*`, but I think that your problem is related to the [Bug #151365: Autosave doesn't work for Unsaved Documents](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/151365)

Comment: It has not been saved at all. I started up gedit, typed away and suddenly the main window disappeared. Autosave is not configured I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file only seemed to be stored in RAM. All attempts to find it on disk returned nothing. Here's what I did for partial recovery:

1. Find out PID and write it down

   ```
   ps -ef | grep gedit
   ```
2. Use it to dump memory of process

   ```
   sudo gcore 12345
   ```
3. Use vim and search for keywords you remember

   ```
   sudo vim core.12345
   ```

The entire file will be fragmented, can be quite big and is littered with parts you have deleted already. Since I was not programming, but wrote an actual text, I was able to find the individual fragments and recover a large part of the text.

Ironically, after I went through all of this work and wanted to close the gedit instance it asked me if I want to save the Untitled Document 1 - which I did.

Comment: You just saved me 4 hours of work! TY

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file with gedit it will create a temporary file with ~ in the name.

so just force close gedit and you can reopen that file

```
gedit /path-to-file/filename~
```

or just go to the directory from nautilus file manager

ctrl + h will show you the hidden file then search for it and open.