# Gedit frozen with invaluable information unsaved

Tags: data-recovery, freeze, gedit

My gedit got frozen for nothing while I wasn't using my computer and it seems to have problems with auto-save + stuff open from google drive via nautilus, so it saved nothing. But I simply can't lose what is unsaved there. It is too much to just remember but since was recent and my computer seemed ok, it was unsaved. So, how can I get what is there? Any method. Whatever.

Comment: is it more than what can be seen? a screen shot maybe

Comment: yes, it is a whole (in details) amazing food recipe I myself invented accidentally, larger than the screen and completely out of that same screen. Plus many small edits I wouldn't completely remember in a large txt recipe book

Comment: You may be helped by [Recover Untitled Document 1 from gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435589/recover-untitled-document-1-from-gedit)

Comment: That gcore trick is essentialy what I needed. TY, I was in total despair.